# Load balancer displays Error 404 page

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I got the following configuration:

```
upstream backend {
  server xx.azurewebsites.net;
  server xxx.azurewebsites.net;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  root /var/www/html;

  server_name_;

  location / {
   proxy_pass http://backend;
  }

}
```

The problem is that the request always returns an Error 404 page: https://i.gyazo.com/cb0b81014aac8ea979ad77b246c79377.png

Accessing xx.azurewebsites.net or xxx.azurewebsites.net via the browser works but not when going through the load balancer. I have tried with other websites too besides azurewebsites.net and they display the 4040 page too.

Does someone know what I'm missing here?

nginx.conf:

```
user Azureuser; // I changed the user from www-user to Azureuser, did't help though
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp:nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2448;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.tyoes;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    gzip on;
    gzip_sidable "msie6";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Loadbalancer: vm-lb-nginx.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com

Server 1: spd1.azurewebsites.net

Server 2: spd2.azurewebsites.net

Comment: Reading point 1 in your blue 404 picture, I wonder whether the DNS indeed has been configured correctly?

Comment: It is, the page can be accessed via internet but not via the loadbalancer for some reason, same goes for other websites too such as Facebook, Fiverr etc.

Comment: But which domain do you use to access the load balancer?

Comment: I access it via IP.

Comment: Can you access the endpoints by ip directly too?

Comment: Yeah I can do that. I tried with the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549006/azure-vm-nginx-plus-web-app-leads-to-404 and it worked but it only sends the traffic to the specified Host which is not really what I want, I want it to balance the load.

Comment: You can set proxy header to $host and configure that in azure. Requires a hostname instead of up approach.

Comment: I tried using $host but that didn't help me, I guess I need to setup a hostname first? How is that done if I may ask?

Comment: You need to set the hostname you want to resolve in the Nginx conf, see basic docs on server_name. That will likely do it for you. Set up appname.tld and configure azure to recognize that.

Comment: I'm not sure if you meant this but I created a DNS for that VM (http://vm-lb-nginx.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/) and added `server_name vm-lb-nginx.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com` to the config file, didn't solve the issue but I might have misunderstood you.

Comment: Don't forget to set up DNS A record from this domain to the ip of the loadbalancer.

Comment: That is already taken care of I guess: https://i.gyazo.com/2818d2618aea1570771bda6da53f76c6.png

Answer (score 0):

```
Ensure your can visit real server through 80 port.please have a try.
If ok, you should check your dns about the domainName.

upstream webservers {
  server xx.azurewebsites.netIP;
  server xxx.azurewebsites.netIP;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;    
    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass   http://webservers; 
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr; 
    }
```

Comment: I just tried your solution but it showing this now: https://i.gyazo.com/cdabedb06729673f7f159dcb4cafb2f2.png All of the 3 servers can be accessed on port 80. EDIT: The index file is also available at the 2 end servers.

Comment: 403 means that you are forbiddened access the web page. Could you paste your the loadbalance part of nginx.conf and the url you vist the real server directly?

Comment: Added the config and URLs to the main post.